# Biconditional Set Theory Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that for all sets $A$ and $B$, $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $A'\cup B = U$.

Hi Math.StackExchange!

I understand that I must prove two things here: First that if $A\subseteq B$ then $A'\cup B = U$, then that if $A'\cup B = U$ then $A\subseteq B$.

I know that if $A\subseteq B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. This is where I got stuck, working with the universal set.

Brand new to Set Theory proofs, so any hints and tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "if A ⊆ B, then x ∈ A and x ∈ B." No, this makes no sense. Check again.

Comment: Please try to use MathJax for future posts; I've linked a useful reference here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets contained in some universal set $U$.

Suppose first that $A \subset B$. Obviously $A^\prime \cup B \subset U$. So we prove the reverse inclusion. Let $x \in U$ be arbitrary. Then either $x \in B$ or $x \not\in B$. If $x \in B$, then $x \in A^\prime \cup B$ as well. If $x \not\in B$, then $x \not\in A$ either because otherwise $x$ would have to be in $B$ also, and thus $x \in A^\prime$, which again implies that $x \in A^\prime \cup B$. Therefore $U \subset A^\prime \cup B$. Hence $$ A^\prime \cup B = U. \tag{1} $$

Conversely, suppose that (1) holds. Let $x \in A$ be arbitrary. Then $x \in U = A^\prime \cup B$, which implies that either $x \in A^\prime$ or $x \in B$, but as $x \in A$, so $x \not\in A^\prime$ and hence $x \in B$. Therefore $$ A \subset B. $$